# Use the residue theorem to evaluate

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$
\int _ {|z|=2} \frac { dz} {(z-4)(z^3-1)}
$$

What I've done now is the following.

$f$ has isolated singularities at $z=4$, $1$, $\exp(\pi i/3)$, $\exp(-\pi i / 3)$

$$
\int _ {|z|=2} \frac { dz} {(z-4)(z^3-1)} = 2 \pi i (\operatorname{Res}(f;1) + \operatorname{Res}(f;\exp(\pi i / 3) + \operatorname{Res}(f;\exp(-\pi i / 3) )
$$

Does it make sense?

And I have lost my way..

In my calculation, Res(f;1) = $\frac 1 {-9}$. But I don't calculate the following 2 values.

Comment: First of all $\exp \pm 2\pi i/3$, not  $\exp \pm \pi i/3$. Also, if you know how to work with complex infinity, you can expand the contour instead of shrinking it. Then the integral will be determined by the single residue at $z=4$, which is equal to $1/63$. I.e. the answer is $-2\pi i/63$.

Comment: I just know complex infinity with respect to stereographic projection. Do you mean by that? I don't understand the meaning of expanding the contour.

Comment: Well when you write $\oint=2\pi i \sum\mathrm{res}$, this usually comes from shrinking the initial contour of integration to small circles around the singularities inside the contour. But, one can instead of that expand and get $\oint=-2\pi i \sum\mathrm{res}$, where the sum is taken over the singularities *outside* the contour. These can also include the infinite point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand fully, but your comment is instructive since I get another viewpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poles are at $z=e^{\pm i 2 \pi/3}$; compute the residues from there.

$$\text{Res}_{z=e^{i 2\pi/3}} \frac{1}{(z-4)(z^3-1)} = \frac{1}{(e^{i 2 \pi/3}-4) 3 e^{i 4 \pi/3}}$$

$$\text{Res}_{z=e^{-i 2\pi/3}} \frac{1}{(z-4)(z^3-1)} = \frac{1}{(e^{-i 2 \pi/3}-4) 3 e^{-i 4 \pi/3}}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how $3 e^{i 4 \pi/3}$ appeared

Comment: @topy: use the formula that the residue of $p(z)/q(z)$ at $z=z_0$ is $p(z_0)/q'(z_0)$.

Comment: What I've done is that $(e^{2\pi i / 3i} - 1)(e^{2\pi i / 3} - e^{-2\pi i / 3}) = (e^{2\pi i / 3i} - 1)(2e^{2\pi i / 3} + 1) $  I think I did something wrong and I can't go further.

Comment: @topy: yeah, you made a mistake in the second factor.  What you should get is $$e^{i 4 \pi/3} - 1 - e^{i 2 \pi/3} + e^{-i 2 \pi/3} = 2 e^{i 4 \pi/3} - e^{i \pi/3} = 3 e^{i 4 \pi/3}$$

Comment: Now, I understand it! Thank you very much!! I had difficulty calculating two complex exponentials.

Comment: It is also hard to calculate the next stage. But I try it! thank you.